# Creating a Linked Server instance from MS SQL Server to a Google Cloud MySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linked-server

I have been attempting to connect the databases of a MSSQL server to a Google Cloud MySQL server so I can do joins between them. I've set up the correct ODBC on my machine and tested the connection, which works fine. But when I go to set up the linked server in the MS Server Management Studio, I get error 7303

> The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do you want to keep the linked server?
>
> Additional information:
>   An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL".
>   OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303

What might I be missing here? I ensured the ODBC driver I have is 64 bits (same as the MS Sever Management I have) but configured the System DSN for 32 bits as well. Is there something I must configure on the Google Cloud Server to make this link work? Since the DSN connection test passes, I assume it must be some failure within the Server Management Studio itself. Thank you!

EDIT: Here is the script used to create the linked server:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'SERVERNAME', @srvproduct=N'MSDASQL', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @datasrc=N'server-name'

GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SERVERNAME', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SERVERNAME', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SERVERNAME', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SERVERNAME', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SERVERNAME', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SERVERNAME', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SERVERNAME', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SERVERNAME', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SERVERNAME', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SERVERNAME', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SERVERNAME', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SERVERNAME', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SERVERNAME', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'SERVERNAME', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False'
GO
```

Comment: SSMS is the client tool, not the server. As for the error, it says there's no ODBC source with that name on the server. Is SQL Server installed on *your* machine? Did you create a User data source or Machine data source?

Comment: I do have SQL server installed on my machine (using SELECT @@ Version it says I have SQL Server 2012, 64-bit). I created a system DSN, whose connection works fine outside the Server Management Studio environment.

Comment: Here is the link from Google, Connection Options for External Applications., https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/external-connection-methods

Comment: I repeat, SSMS is the *client tool*. The error comes from the *server*. SSMS was able to execute the commands that create the linked server. When it tried to *check* the connection though, it got an error.

Comment: Please post the commands used to create the linked server. Almost all dialog boxes in SSMS have a `script` button at the top

Comment: I have added the command used to create the linked server. Hope that helps diagnose the issue!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, in fact this is a client error.
You don't have the MSDASQL driver installed on your client machine, or possibly you only have a version that your client tool can't connect to -- such as 32-bit while you're running a 64-bit client.

It is normal that you can create the Linked Server without an error.
The driver is not checked by sp_addlinkedserver;  it just creates the relevant table entries.

To easily see what drivers you do have, try the visual ODBC Data Sources tool.
You can start the process of creating a DNS and get see all the driver names.  It may have only the long names, but those also work.